# Extract & structure a CSV file from a plain text file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a plain text file that I would like to use as the source to produce a CSV file.

The format of the text file:
[image: example plain text]

The VBA code should use the source file to apply logic and save the file as a CSV.

The logic:

1. Flight Number is the code that starts with SF following by number.
   Example: SF1234
2. Flight date should be calculated as it follows:
   if the string contains 19APR23 19APR23, it means that it is one day 19/04/2023.
   if the string contains 19APR23 21APR23 then for the same flight number there should be three lines as they are three days.

| Flight Number | Flight Date | Template | Widget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SF1234 | 19/04/2023 |  |  |
| SF1234 | 19/04/2023 |  |  |
| SF1234 | 20/04/2023 |  |  |
| SF1234 | 21/04/2023 |  |  |

I tried the following code, but it produces a CSV with just "Flight Number, Flight Date, Template,Widget" and no data:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportSSMData()
Dim SSMFileName As Variant
Dim SSMFile As Integer
Dim SSMContent As String
Dim SSMData() As String
Dim FlightNum As String
Dim FlightDates As String
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim CurrentDate As Date
Dim OutputWorkbook As Workbook
Dim OutputWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim OutputRow As Long
Dim i As Long

SSMFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Select the SSM file")

If SSMFileName = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

SSMFile = FreeFile
Open SSMFileName For Input As SSMFile
SSMContent = Input(LOF(SSMFile), SSMFile)
Close SSMFile

SSMData = Split(SSMContent, vbCrLf)

Set OutputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
Set OutputWorksheet = OutputWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

OutputRow = 1
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = "Flight Number"
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = "Flight Date"
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 3).Value = "Template"
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 4).Value = "Widget"

For i = LBound(SSMData) To UBound(SSMData)
    If Left(SSMData(i), 2) = "SF" Then
        FlightNum = SSMData(i)
    ElseIf Len(SSMData(i)) >= 7 And IsDate(Left(SSMData(i), 7)) Then
        FlightDates = SSMData(i)

        If Len(FlightDates) >= 14 Then
            StartDate = DateSerial(Right(FlightDates, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 5, 3)), Left(FlightDates, 2))
            EndDate = DateSerial(Right(FlightDates, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 12, 3)), Mid(FlightDates, 10, 2))

            For CurrentDate = StartDate To EndDate
                OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = FlightNum
                OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = Format(CurrentDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Next CurrentDate
        ElseIf Len(FlightDates) >= 7 Then
            StartDate = DateSerial(Right(FlightDates, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 5, 3)), Left(FlightDates, 2))
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
            OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = FlightNum
            OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = Format(StartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            
        End If
    End If
Next i


Dim CSVFileName As Variant

CSVFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=Replace(SSMFileName, ".txt", ".csv"), _
    FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
    Title:="Save the CSV file")

If CSVFileName <> False Then
    OutputWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=CSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    OutputWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Else
    MsgBox "No file name was provided. The file was not saved.", vbExclamation, "Save Canceled"
End If
End Sub

Function MonthNameToNumber(MonthName As String) As Integer
Dim MonthNumber As Integer
Dim MonthNames As Variant
MonthNames = Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")

For MonthNumber = LBound(MonthNames) To UBound(MonthNames)
    If UCase(MonthName) = MonthNames(MonthNumber) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next MonthNumber

MonthNameToNumber = MonthNumber + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Saving as .csv will remove all formatting and any formulas. When opening a csv you can use text to columns to split the text by using the comma separator. I don't know why you would have no data. I was trying your code and couldn't get past the "EndDate" line

Comment: @Davesexcel thank you so much for checking my code... I am actually wondering the same as I should have data and I don't understand why it does not work...

Comment: Where has the text file come from ? Maybe vbCrLf is not the line ending, you can check with notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for similar solutions, I have fixed the code that works now:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportSSMData()
Dim SSMFileName As Variant
Dim SSMFile As Integer
Dim SSMContent As String
Dim SSMData() As String
Dim FlightNum As String
Dim FlightDates As String

Dim FlightDateStart As String
Dim FlightDatesEnd As String

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

Dim DeltaDate As Integer

Dim CurrentDate As Date
Dim OutputWorkbook As Workbook
Dim OutputWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim OutputRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long

SSMFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Select the SSM file")

If SSMFileName = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

SSMFile = FreeFile
Open SSMFileName For Input As SSMFile
SSMContent = Input(LOF(SSMFile), SSMFile)
Close SSMFile

SSMData = Split(SSMContent, vbCrLf)

Set OutputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
Set OutputWorksheet = OutputWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

OutputRow = 1
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = "Flight Number"
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = "Flight Date"
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 3).Value = "Template"
OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 4).Value = "Widget"



    For i = LBound(SSMData) To UBound(SSMData)
    If Left(SSMData(i), 1) <> "#" Then
        If Left(SSMData(i), 2) = "SF" Then
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
            FlightNum = SSMData(i)
            OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = FlightNum
                    
        
           
        ElseIf Len(SSMData(i)) >= 16 Then
            FlightDates = SSMData(i)
            FlightDateStart = Left(SSMData(i), 7)
            FlightDatesEnd = Mid(SSMData(i), 9, 6)
            StartDate = DateSerial(Mid(FlightDates, 6, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 3, 3)), Left(FlightDates, 2))
            EndDate = DateSerial(Mid(FlightDates, 14, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 11, 3)), Mid(FlightDates, 9, 2))
             
             DeltaDate = EndDate - StartDate
             
             OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = StartDate
            
       
             
             If DeltaDate = 0 Then
             
                OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = StartDate
                
            Else
                For y = 0 To DeltaDate
                   
                    OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = FlightNum
                    OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = StartDate
                    
                    If y < DeltaDate Then
                        OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                        StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate)
                     End If
                Next y
            End If
             
        End If
    End If
    Next i


Dim CSVFileName As Variant

CSVFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=Replace(SSMFileName, ".txt", ".csv"), _
    FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
    Title:="Save the CSV file")

If CSVFileName <> False Then
    OutputWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=CSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    OutputWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Else
    MsgBox "No file name was provided. The file was not saved.", vbExclamation, "Save Canceled"
End If
End Sub

Function MonthNameToNumber(MonthName As String) As Integer
Dim MonthNumber As Integer
Dim MonthNames As Variant
MonthNames = Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")

For MonthNumber = LBound(MonthNames) To UBound(MonthNames)
    If UCase(MonthName) = MonthNames(MonthNumber) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next MonthNumber

MonthNameToNumber = MonthNumber + 1
End Function

Function IsCompactDate(DateString As String) As Boolean
    IsCompactDate = IsDate(Left(DateString, 2) & " " & Mid(DateString, 3, 3) & " " & Mid(DateString, 6, 2))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code:

##### Compact dates

You can't use `IsDate` for dates with the syntax 19APR23. You can use something like this instead:

```
Function IsCompactDate(DateString As String) As Boolean
    IsCompactDate = IsDate(Left(DateString, 2) & " " & Mid(DateString, 3, 3) & " " & Mid(DateString, 6, 2))
End Function
```

##### String extraction

There is a recurring error with `Right` where it should be `Mid`. `Right(FlightDates,2)` only works if you really want the two last characters of that string. In most cases in this problem, you don't have the year at the very end. Use `Mid` instead. Also, there are some logic errors related to this.
I have made a few changes to your loop based on this. Not sure if it is perfectly correct, but it will send you in the right direction I hope.

```
For i = LBound(SSMData) To UBound(SSMData)
    If Left(SSMData(i), 2) = "SF" Then
        FlightNum = SSMData(i)
    ElseIf Len(SSMData(i)) >= 7 And IsCompactDate(Left(SSMData(i), 7)) Then
        FlightDates = SSMData(i)

        If IsCompactDate(Mid(SSMData(i), 10, 7)) Then
            StartDate = DateSerial(Mid(FlightDates, 6, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 3, 3)), Left(FlightDates, 2))
            EndDate = DateSerial(Mid(FlightDates, 14, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 11, 3)), Mid(FlightDates, 9, 2))

            For CurrentDate = StartDate To EndDate
                OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = FlightNum
                OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = Format(CurrentDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Next CurrentDate
        ElseIf Len(FlightDates) >= 7 Then
            StartDate = DateSerial(Mid(FlightDates, 6, 2), MonthNameToNumber(Mid(FlightDates, 5, 3)), Left(FlightDates, 2))
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
            OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = FlightNum
            OutputWorksheet.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = Format(StartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sam. Indeed the solution gets me closer to the final result :)

Still, I need to figure it out how to fix the date format. For instance if the source format is 19APR23 19APR23 3, for some reason the csv reports 28/01/2001 instead of 19/04/2023. 

Also if the format is 19APR23 21APR23 3, it doesn't create 3 lines for the same Flight Number (19/04/2023, 20/04/2023, 21/04/2023). 

In any case, thanks for your support as at least now it creates the csv with data

Comment: A hint (without actually checking it) is that American dates are not the same as others. Think about the order of fields. Also, put `Debug.Print FlightDates` at stragical places in your code and study up on how the debugger works.

Comment: When checking your CSV, DO NOT open in excel, open in notepad. Excel applies misleading formatting